# Extract HashMap from an ArrayList of Hashmap by using lambda expression with Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

[image: Please check Data structure image here]

I need to find a Hashmap whose is_default value is equal to 1.

Noted: In this structure, only 1 hashmap contains is_default value is equal to 1.

Comment: extract in what way? Are you going to show your attempt at doing this?

Comment: Was your problem solved? Could you give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check those maps that contain the required key. After that, you need to choose from them the one with the desired value of this key. It can be done with `filter`

```
list.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.containsKey("is_default"))
    .filter(x -> x.get("is_default")
                  .compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you can use `getOrDefault` and specify wrong value as default to skip those maps that do not contain a key

```
list.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getOrDefault("is_default", BigDecimal.ZERO)
                  .compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, BigDecimal>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // target
    Map<String, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("is_default", BigDecimal.ONE);
    map.put("key", BigDecimal.TEN);
    list.add(map);

    Map<String, BigDecimal> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("is_default", BigDecimal.ZERO);
    map2.put("key", BigDecimal.ZERO);
    list.add(map2);

    Map<String, BigDecimal> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("isnt_default", BigDecimal.ZERO);
    list.add(map3);

    list.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.containsKey("is_default"))
        .filter(x -> x.get("is_default")
                      .compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output

```
{is_default=1, key=10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> list = List.of(
        Map.of("is_default", "0", "label", "test0"),
        Map.of("is_default", "1", "label", "test1"),
        Map.of("is_default", "2", "label", "test2"));
    Map<String, String> extracted = list.stream()
        .filter(map -> Objects.equals(map.get("is_default"), "1"))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
    System.out.println(extracted);
}
```

output:

```
{label=test1, is_default=1}
```